# ¿De que manera puedo generar una sincronización de base de datos?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, delphi

Tengo la siguiente duda.

Supongamos que una empresa que emite boletos para excursiones en barco tiene dos puntos de venta en distintos lugares. Actualmente estos dos puntos de venta no tienen ningun tipo de conexiín entre sí, por ende la unica manera de saber si se vendieron todos los boletos es literalmente llamando a quien este en el otro punto para preguntarle cuantos lugares le quedan.

Desarrollé un sistema para generar dichos boletos/pasajes en Delphi XE7. Ahora me falta una manera de sincronizar los puntos de venta.

Mi objetivo es que si yo emito un boleto en el punto de venta "A" y es el boleto "Nº: 0003" cuando el punto de venta "B" emita un boleto este sea el "Nº: 0004".

Y de la misma manera lograr que cuando se llene el barco y no haya mas boletos disponibles los dos sistemas no puedan vender mas boletos en ese viaje.

Basicamente, solucionar esta situacion de tener que llamar al otro punto y preguntarle cuantos boletos quedan.

Investigué un poco sobre la replicación de bases de datos en MySQL (Master-slave) pero por lo visto es unidereccional, por ende uno de los dos puntos de venta no podria modificar la base de datos.

¿Alguna sugerencia de como puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Que la base de datos esté centralizada? Que asignes rangos de boletos diferentes a cada punto? Que haya un servicio intermedio de "asignación de ID de boletos" que cada punto de venta consuma y así la concurrencia la gestiona ese servicio (SOAP, REST o como quieras hacerlo)? Depende de tus requerimientos no funcionales

Comment: Suponiendo que el internet es un factor que puede fallar con regularidad. ¿Cual podria ser la mejor opcion?

Comment: Si el internet del cliente falla, no hay más que hacer, a menos de que quieras ocupar otros protocolos de transmisión de información. Si el internet del cliente falla, no afecta a la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución "correcta" (ideal) y las más sencilla (la que menos problemas te va a dar) es que esos 2 puntos de venta trabajen contra la misma Base de Datos.
Lo que tienes que ver, es qué soluciones tienes para conseguir eso. Una **VPN** parece algo sencillo y que no te debería conllevar cambios en el programa.
Si por temas técnicos esta solución no es posible, hay que evaluar alternativas, pero creo que entonces estás condicionando la solución del problema, no sólo al problema en sí, sino a otros factores externos.

***(OBLIGATORIO)***
Está claro que **necesitas conexión a internet** para poder solventar este problema, porque tiene que haber un **lugar común donde ambos puntos de venta puedan leer y escribir** la información.

Si me dices que la conexión falla, es imposible que puedas comunicar ambos puntos con fiabilidad.

**OTRAS OPCIONES (parches):**
(0) Utilizar algo como **"RAD Server"**, pero hablando de que estamos desarollando un parche, creo que no vale la pena ni evaluarlo.

(1) **Crear un WebService** sencillo en un Servidor de Internet, que te vaya dando los boletos y el estado del barco (barco Lleno/Vacío).
En ese caso los clientes se comunican con el WS cada ver que hacen una venta (antes y después), proceso sencillo.
[Revisa esta serie de entradas](https://neftali.clubdelphi.com/15-aplicacion-de-acceso-a-datos-introduccion/), que explica cómo hacer esto de forma sencilla. Tanto el servidor como los clientes.

(2) Opción que usábamos antes cuando no había WS. **Utilizar un FTP/FTPs** de los de toda la vida para compartir información, realizando pooling cada x tiempo. Tanto para leer como para escribir. Sincronización manual.
Menos recomendable que la anterior, pero posiblemente más sencilla técnicamente.

(3) Utilizar otros espacios (en internet) para realizar la misma sincronización del punto anterior. Mismo problemas y carencias del anterior. Léase, DropBox, GDrive, OneDrive,...

Puede haber más pero contando que **cuanto más abajo en menos recomendable** y que ya nos basamos en que son un parche, ya no sigo ni proponiendo...